# Replace Boolean value with Image Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I have a few Boolean Fields in a Django Form Class. I go to query the data, and everything works fine, but I want to replace the booleans with text or an image. So instead of "Item: False", it would be a custom piece of text, or ideally, and image or lack of one to denote the T/F. I Googled around, and saw the "yesno" for Django, but nothing for Djangop Forms oh GAE. Any one experienced with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each django form uses a default Widget to render the form to HTML.  You can create your own custom widget to generate HTML to show the image you want.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/widgets/